# Getting error C2440 with array and I don't know why

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am working on a very simple console chess game and I keep getting and error and I do not know why. Here is part of my code:

```
string board[8][8] = {
"BR",  "BKn",  "BB",  "BQ",  "BKi",  "BB",  "BKn",  "BR", 
"BP",  "BP",  "BP",  "BP",  "BP",  "BP",  "BP",  "BP", 
"0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0", 
"0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0", 
"0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0", 
"0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0",  "0", 
"WP",  "WP",  "WP",  "WP",  "WP",  "WP",  "WP",  "WP", 
"WR",  "WKn",  "WB",  "WKi",  "WQ",  "WB",  "WKn",  "WR"
};

void setBoard(string piece, string side, int where1, int where2) {
if (side == "white") {
    if (piece == "rook") {
        board[where1, where2] = "WR"; //All lines like this get an error
    }
    else if (piece == "knight") {
        board[where1, where2] = "WKn";
    }
    else if (piece == "bishop") {
        board[where1, where2] = "WB";
    }
    else if (piece == "king") {
        board[where1, where2] = "WKi";
    }
    else if (piece == "queen") {
        board[where1, where2] = "WQ";
    }
    else if (piece == "pawn") {
        board[where1, where2] = "WP";
    }
}
else if (side == "black") {
    if (piece == "rook") {
        board[where1, where2] = "BR";
    }
    else if (piece == "knight") {
        board[where1, where2] = "Bkn";
    }
    else if (piece == "bishop") {
        board[where1, where2] = "BB";
    }
    else if (piece == "king") {
        board[where1, where2] = "BKi";
    }
    else if (piece == "queen") {
        board[where1, where2] = "BQ";
    }
    else if (piece == "pawn") {
        board[where1, where2] = "BP";
    }
}
}

void play(string where) {
bool second = false;
char first = where[0];
int x = conv1(first);

int sec = where[1];
sec -= 48;
int y = conv2(sec);

if (x == 69 || y == 69) {
    cout << "Error: Not a valid space. Make sure the letter is capitalized." << endl;
    chess();
}
else {
    if (board[x][y] != "0") {
        if (second == false) {
            string piece = getPiece(board[x][y]);
            cout << "Where do you want to move the piece " << piece << " ?" << endl;
            string input; cin >> input;
            play(input);
        }
        else if (second == true) {
            string piece = getPiece(board[x][y]);
            cout << "Are you sure you want move the piece " << piece << " to the space " << where << " ?" << endl << "Yes(1) \nNo(2)" << endl;
            int choice; cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 1) {
                string side = getSide(board[x][y]);
                setBoard(piece, side, x, y);
            }
            else chess();
        }
    }
    else cout << "Error: There is no piece on space " << where << " ." << endl;
}
}
```

It is giving me this error:

> Error    1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [3]' to
>   'std::string [8]'

I do not know what is wrong with my code, can anyone tell me what is happening. Also, I can change the value of board without problem in the play function, it is just when I try to do it there it gets mad at me.

Comment: You have `string board[8][8]`, but you try to initialize it with 64 string literals. You should wrap each line in braces to form its own array

Comment: Oh your right @eukaryota. I think that's the problem lol. I wish visual studio would just tell me that.

Comment: @Justin it is fine to initialize `std::string`  from a string literal. Also it is fine to use one braced list to initialize a multi-dimensional array (initializers are taken in row major order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is due to the way the double index is used:

```
board[where1, where2]
```

This is not actually indexing the two-dimensional array. Rather the `,` operator evaluates both operands, e.g. `where1` and `where2` and returns the value of the latter.

Therefore the expression will behave the same as

```
board[where2]
```

which is of type `std::string[8]` and therefore assigning a string literal of type `const char[3]` is not possible.

Correct indexing is done using applying the subscript operator twice:

```
board[where1][where2]
```